# Receive messages from Azure IotHub in xamarin .netstandard

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-iot-hub, .net-standard-2.0

I am developing the xamarin app in .netStandard 2.0 using visual studio 2019.I have a problem to received data from iothub.I able to send data from xamarin app to iot hub but unable to  received data from azure iothub.

**Liberies**

1. Microsoft.Azure.Device (1.20.0)
2. Microsoft.Azure.Device.Client (1.24.0)

   ```
   private const string DeviceConnectionString = "HostName=[your hostname];DeviceId=[your DeviceId];SharedAccessKey=[your shared key]";
   public async Task Start()
   {
   try
    {
       DeviceClient deviceClient = 
       DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString, TransportType.http1);
       await SendEvent(deviceClient);
       await ReceiveCommands(deviceClient);
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("Error in sample: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
   }
   async Task SendEvent(DeviceClient deviceClient)
   {
   string dataBuffer;        
   dataBuffer = "Hello Iot";
   Message eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataBuffer));
   await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(eventMessage);

   }
   async Task ReceiveCommands(DeviceClient deviceClient)
   {
   Message receivedMessage;
   string messageData;
   while (true)
   {
       receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
       if (receivedMessage != null)
       {
           messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
           txtblkMessages.Text = messageData + "\n" + txtblkMessages.Text;
           await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
       }

       await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: do you want to receive Cloud2Devices messages or the messages sent by devices to the IoT Hub (Device2Cloud)?

Comment: I want to receive Device2Cloud message.

Comment: I'm afraid you are looking at the wrong thing then. You need to read the messages from the eventhub-compatible endpoint. For example using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-dotnet-standard-send-v2#receive-events

Comment: I am not talking about .net core,already i have a algorithm in .net framework to receive event/data from iothub .Now i need to receive data in .net standard xamarin mobile apps.Thanks

Comment: then just go for this one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#receive-events

Comment: @FarazSaleem One of the solution can be using the **Azure SignalR Service** for pushing the telemetry data via the *Azure Event Grid* to the xamarin mobile apps, for instance to the android. Using the Azure Function with a SignalR binding and batching feature for subscriber handler will simplified its implementation.

Comment: @RomanKiss Thanks for the suggestion i will try to implement by azure SignalR.